# Using Multiple aggregate functions in the where clause

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

We have a select statement in production that takes quite a lot of time.
The current query uses row number - window function.
I am trying to rewrite the query and test the same. assuming its orc table fetching aggregate values instead of using row number may help to reduce the execution time, is my assumption

Is something like this possible. Let me know if i am missing anything.
Sorry i am trying to learn, so please bear with my mistakes, if any. 
I tried to rewrite the query as mentioned below.

Original query

```
SELECT
Q.id,
Q.crt_ts,
Q.upd_ts,
Q.exp_ts,
Q.biz_effdt
(
SELECT u.id, u.crt_ts, u.upd_ts, u.exp_ts, u.biz_effdt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY u.crt_ts DESC) AS ROW_N
FROM ( SELECT cust_prd.id, cust_prd.crt_ts, cust_prd.upd_ts, cust_prd.exp_ts,  cust_prd.biz_effdt FROM MSTR_CORE.cust_prd 
        WHERE biz_effdt IN ( SELECT MAX(cust_prd.biz_effdt) FROM MSTR_CORE.cust_prd )
     ) U
)Q WHERE Q.row_n = 1
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT cust_prd.id, cust_prd.crt_ts, cust_prd.upd_ts, cust_prd.exp_ts,  cust_prd.biz_effdt FROM MSTR_CORE.cust_prd 
WHERE biz_effdt IN ( SELECT MAX(cust_prd.biz_effdt) FROM MSTR_CORE.cust_prd ) 
having cust_prd.crt_ts = max (cust_prd.crt_ts)
```

Comment: Provide query plan.  Most likely need indexes

Comment: hello @SaadAhmad, as this is hive, we dont apply indexes. although we can use set options at session level to apply vectorization and all. as there are no joins , capturing statistics may help here

Comment: Granted that my knowledge is limited, are you sure about no indexes.  It is 2019 after all.  See https://www.google.com/amp/s/acadgild.com/blog/indexing-in-hive/amp